# Count rows within each group when condition is satisfied Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, group-by

I have at table which looks like below:

```
         ID            Date     IsFull
         1          2020-01-05    0 
         1          2020-02-05    0  
         1          2020-02-25    1  
         1          2020-03-01    1
         1          2020-03-20    1
```

I want to display how many months for  ID = 1

have sum(isfull)/count(*) > .6 in a given month (More than 60% of the times in that month isfull = 1)

So the final output should

```
 ID     HowManyMonths
  1       1     --------(Only month 3----2 out 2 cases)
```

If the question changes to  sum(isfull)/count(*) > .4

then the final output should be

```
  ID     HowManyMonths
   1       2     --------(Month 2 and Month 3)
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with two levels of aggregation:

```
select id, count(*) howManyMonths
from (
    select id
    from mytable
    group by id, year(date), month(date)
    having avg(1.0 * isFull) > 0.6
) t
group by id
```

The subquery aggregates by id, year and month, and uses a `having` clause to filter on groups that meet the success rate (`avg()` comes handy for this). The outer query counts how many month passed the target rate for each id.